# Parallel delete with broadcast distribution

Tags: oracle, parallel-processing, explain, sql-execution-plan

I have a big fact table and a stage table with ~ 12K job's pk that need to be loaded. prior to creating the new data i want to delete the part of the old data that is about to be inserted.

`FACT` is partitioned but by a different column then the join predicate.
`ETL` table ~12k rows, ~440KB compressed size. 
Each key in `ETL` has about 30-50 rows in `FACT` so i'm expecting about ~400K deletes.
Stats are up to date.

```
explain plan for
delete  from fact f
      where  exists (
        select 1
        from  etl e
        where (e.id = f.id and e.somedate = f.somedate)
        or    (e.other_id = f.other_id)
      )


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |Pstart| Pstop|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | DELETE STATEMENT      |         |     1 |    43 |    14M  (8)| 49:41:52 |       |     |
|   1 |  DELETE               | FACT    |       |       |            |          |       |     |
|*  2 |   FILTER              |         |       |       |            |          |       |     |
|   3 |    PARTITION RANGE ALL|         |  1219K|    50M|  7797   (3)| 00:01:34 |     1 | 15  |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL | FACT    |  1219K|    50M|  7797   (3)| 00:01:34 |     1 | 15  |
|*  5 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL  | ETL     |     2 |    38 |    13   (8)| 00:00:01 |       |     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The basic scenario, Serial execution, very slow and inefficient.

Thought i might speed things up with parallel execution :

```
explain plan for
delete /*+ PARALLEL(f,4) */ from fact f
      where  exists (
        select 1
        from  etl e
        where (e.id = f.id and e.somedate = f.somedate)
        or    (e.other_id = f.other_id)
      )

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | DELETE STATEMENT       |          |     1 |    43 |    14M  (8)| 49:40:44 |       |       |        |      |            |
|   1 |  DELETE                | FACT     |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |
|*  2 |   FILTER               |          |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |
|   3 |    PX COORDINATOR      |          |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |
|   4 |     PX SEND QC (RANDOM)| :TQ10000 |  1219K|    50M|  2152   (2)| 00:00:26 |       |       |  Q1,00 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   5 |      PX BLOCK ITERATOR |          |  1219K|    50M|  2152   (2)| 00:00:26 |     1 |    15 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|   6 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL| FACT     |  1219K|    50M|  2152   (2)| 00:00:26 |     1 |    15 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|*  7 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL   | ETL      |     2 |    38 |    13   (8)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |      |            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Reading the plan I'm not sure whats parallel about it. The px processes are scanning the table and sending blocks up to the coordinator for filtering. This is still not very efficient. If any, I think the process allocation, dispatching and syncing might even make it worst.

So, I though, `ETL` is so small (~500K) - why shouldn't oracle split the tables randomly across the px process and broadcast a copy of ETL to each one. Oracle is doing the exact same thing with small NL joins using broadcast. This way I'm getting the full parallel experience. So i'm trying to make oracle carry out this execution plan but haven't succeeded so far

```
explain plan for
delete /*+ PARALLEL(f,4) PQ_DISTRIBUTE(@j e BROADCAST, NONE) */ from fact f
      where  exists (
        select /*+ QB_NAME(j) */ 1
        from  etl e
        where (e.id = f.id and e.somedate = f.somedate)
        or    (e.other_id = f.other_id)
      )
```

I'm getting the same execution plan as above.

Comment: Can you post a sqlfiddle by mocking the  row nums using DBMS Stats??

Comment: I don't think its a stats issue - The question here is if it's even possible. Hints override stats.

Comment: mostly local bitmaps & global PK

Answer (score 0):

i would try answering to ur problem (not to ur question).

1) The plan shows, CBO finds just 2 matching rows in ETL against 1.2 mn rows in FACT table. This is contrary to what you mentioned above. So, this looks to be stats issue and it does matter with parallel hint.

So, i would gather stats on both tables and give it a try.

2) Even if Oracle will use Parallel Execution feature, it might get even worse then before (like what happens if it chooses a wrong index). Therefore, i would avoid any hint at first place.

In both (no hint/hint) cases, don't just reply on expected plan but execute and analyse actual plan.

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor);     --actual plan
```

3) If data in ETL can be of diverse range, it will make CBO traverse all partitions in FACT table. So, Creating a global index to support join condition would help.

4) I would also suggest using MERGE to achieve ur dual goal of DELETE & INSERT.